# Is there a BASH protection on remote copy of root files?

Tags: bash, shell-script, remote

I am trying to use a script to bring back log to the admin.
This script is send and load via mussh on the remote machine

```
#!/bin/bash
scp files.log user@user:~/
```

(I have also tried with sudo scp ... but same result)

.The permission are ok for root login via ssh

.The authorized_keys is set correctly

But, each times I try to load the script from remote via mussh

```
mussh -a -i /home/the_user/.ssh/key -d -H hostfile -c ' sh script-to-bring-back-log.sh' -m2
```

It give me back:

Permission denied

Permission denied

Permission denied (publickey,password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something going wrong in mussh.  I can reproduce your problem and will fix it in the next release.

As a workaround, I recommend you use the following.

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add /home/the_user/.ssh/key
mussh -d -H hostfile -c ' sh script-to-bring-back-log.sh' -m2
eval $(ssh-agent -k)
```